# dagger Tutorial cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I implemented Dagger tutorial till end of https://dagger.dev/tutorial/11-withdraw-command. In compiling the program I receive this error

> java: [Dagger/MissingBinding] main.Database.Account cannot be provided
> without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
> main.Database.Account is injected at
> main.DepositCommand(account, …)
> main.DepositCommand is injected at
> main.UserCommandsModule.depositCommand(command)
> java.util.Map<java.lang.String,main.Command> is injected at
> main.CommandRouter(commands)
> main.CommandRouter is injected at
> main.CommandProcessor(firstCommandRouter)
> main.CommandProcessor is requested at
> main.CommandProcessorFactory.commandProcessor()   It is also requested at:
> main.WithdrawCommand(…, account, …)   The following other entry points also depend on it:
> main.UserCommandsRouter.router() [main.CommandProcessorFactory → main.UserCommandsRouter]

Please help to solve this error.

Thanks alot

My AmountModule class:

```
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Module
interface AmountsModule {
@Provides
@MinimumBalance
static BigDecimal minimumBalance() {
return BigDecimal.ZERO;
}

    @Provides
    @MaximumWithdrawal
    static BigDecimal maximumWithdrawal() {
        return new BigDecimal(1000);
    }

}
```

BigDecimal Class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

 abstract class BigDecimalCommand extends SingleArgCommand {

    private final Outputter outputter;


    protected BigDecimalCommand(Outputter outputter) {
        this.outputter = outputter;
    }

    @Override
    protected final Result handleArg(String arg) {
        BigDecimal amount = tryParse(arg);
        if (amount == null) {
            outputter.output(arg + " is not a valid number");
        } else if (amount.signum() <= 0) {
            outputter.output("amount must be positive");
        } else {
            handleAmount(amount);
       
 }
        return Result.handled();

    }

    private static BigDecimal tryParse(String arg) {
        try {
            return new BigDecimal(arg);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /** Handles the given (positive) {@code amount} of money. */
    protected abstract void handleAmount(BigDecimal amount);
}
```

Command Class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface Command {
    /**
     * String token that signifies this command should be selected (e.g.:
     * "deposit", "withdraw")
     */
    //String key();

    /**
     * Process the rest of the command's words and do something.
     */
    Result handleInput(List<String> input);

    final class Result {
        private final Status status;
        private final Optional<CommandRouter> nestedCommandRouter;

        private Result(Status status, Optional<CommandRouter> nestedCommandRouter) {
            this.status = status;
            this.nestedCommandRouter = nestedCommandRouter;
        }

        static Result invalid() {
            return new Result(Status.INVALID, Optional.empty());
        }

        static Result handled() {
            return new Result(Status.HANDLED, Optional.empty());
        }

        Status status() {
            return status;
        }

        Optional<CommandRouter> nestedCommandRouter() {
            return nestedCommandRouter;
        }

        static Result enterNestedCommandSet(CommandRouter nestedCommandRouter) {
            return new Result(Status.HANDLED, Optional.of(nestedCommandRouter));
        }
    }

    enum Status {
        INVALID,
        HANDLED,
        INPUT_COMPLETED
    }
}
```

CommandProcessor class:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import main.Command.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
final class CommandProcessor {
    private final Deque<CommandRouter> commandRouterStack = new ArrayDeque<>();

    @Inject
    CommandProcessor(CommandRouter firstCommandRouter) {
        commandRouterStack.push(firstCommandRouter);
    }

    Status process(String input) {
        Result result = commandRouterStack.peek().route(input);
        if (result.status().equals(Status.INPUT_COMPLETED)) {
            commandRouterStack.pop();
            return commandRouterStack.isEmpty()
                    ? Status.INPUT_COMPLETED : Status.HANDLED;
        }
        result.nestedCommandRouter().ifPresent(commandRouterStack::push);
        return result.status();
    }
}
```

CommandProcessorFactory class:

```
import dagger.Component;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

//@Component(modules = {HelloWorldModule.class,SystemOutModule.class})
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        LoginCommandModule.class,
        HelloWorldModule.class,
        SystemOutModule.class,
        UserCommandsModule.class,
        UserCommandsRouter.InstallationModule.class,
        AmountsModule.class
       })

public interface CommandProcessorFactory {
    CommandProcessor commandProcessor();
}
```

CommandRouter Class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.*;
import main.Command.*;

final public class CommandRouter {
    private final Map<String, Command> commands;

//    @Inject
//    CommandRouter(HelloWorldCommand helloWorldCommand) {
//        commands.put(helloWorldCommand.key(), helloWorldCommand);
//    }
    @Inject
    CommandRouter(Map<String,Command> commands){
        this.commands = commands;
    }
    Result route(String input) {
        List<String> splitInput = split(input);
        if (splitInput.isEmpty()) {
            return invalidCommand(input);
        }

        String commandKey = splitInput.get(0);
        Command command = commands.get(commandKey);
        if (command == null) {
            return invalidCommand(input);
        }

        List<String> args = splitInput.subList(1, splitInput.size());
        Result result = command.handleInput(args);
        return result.status().equals(Status.INVALID) ?
                invalidCommand(input) : result;
    }

    private Result invalidCommand(String input) {
        System.out.println(
                String.format("couldn't understand \"%s\". please try again.", input));
        return Result.invalid();
    }

    // Split on whitespace
    private static List<String> split(String input) {
        return Arrays.asList(input.trim().split("\\s+"));
    }
}
```

Datebase Class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Singleton
public class Database {
    private final Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();

    @Inject
    Database() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    Account getAccount(String username) {
        System.out.println("getAccount InDB");
        return accounts.computeIfAbsent(username, Account::new);

    }

    static final class Account {
        private final String username;
        private BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        Account(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        String username() {
            return username;
        }

        BigDecimal balance() {
            return balance;
        }

        void deposit(BigDecimal amount) {
            balance = balance.add(amount);
        }

        void withdraw(BigDecimal amount) {
            balance = balance.subtract(amount);
        }

    }


}
```

DepositCommand Class:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import main.Database.*;


import javax.inject.Inject;

final class DepositCommand extends BigDecimalCommand {
    private final Account account;
    private final Outputter outputter;

    @Inject
    DepositCommand(Account account, Outputter outputter) {
        super(outputter);
        this.account = account;
        this.outputter = outputter;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        account.deposit(amount);
        outputter.output(account.username() + " now has: " + account.balance());
    }
}
```

HelloWorldCommand Class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorldCommand implements Command {
    private final Outputter outputter;
    @Inject
    HelloWorldCommand(Outputter outputter) {
        this.outputter = outputter;
    }

//    @Override
//    public String key() {
//        return "hellom";
//    }

    @Override
    public Result handleInput(List<String> input) {
        if (!input.isEmpty()) {
            return Result.invalid();
        }
       outputter.output("World!!");
        return Result.handled();
    }
}
```

HelloworldModule:

```
import dagger.Binds;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.multibindings.IntoMap;
import dagger.multibindings.StringKey;

@Module
abstract public class HelloWorldModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @StringKey("hello")
    abstract Command helloWorldCommand(HelloWorldCommand command);
}
```

LoginCommand Class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import main.Database.*;

public class LoginCommand extends SingleArgCommand{
private final Outputter outputter;
private final Database database;
private final UserCommandsRouter.Factory userCommandsRouterFactory;
@Inject
LoginCommand(Database database
,Outputter outputter
,UserCommandsRouter.Factory userCommandsRouterFactory) {
this.outputter = outputter;
this.database = database;
this.userCommandsRouterFactory = userCommandsRouterFactory;
System.out.println(this);
}

//    @Override
//    public String key() {
//        return "login";
//    }

    @Override
    public Result handleArg(String username) {
        Account account = database.getAccount(username);
        outputter.output(
                username + " is logged in with balance: " + account.balance());
        return Result.enterNestedCommandSet(
                userCommandsRouterFactory.create(account).router());
    }

}
```

LoginCommandModule

```
import dagger.Binds;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.multibindings.IntoMap;
import dagger.multibindings.StringKey;

@Module
abstract class LoginCommandModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @StringKey("login")
    abstract Command loginCommand(LoginCommand command);
}
```

Main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import main.Command.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       // CommandRouter commandRouter = new CommandRouter();

//        CommandProcessorFactory commandProcessorFactory =
//                DaggerCommandRouterFactory.create();
//        CommandRouter commandRouter = commandProcessorFactory.router();
        CommandProcessorFactory commandProcessorFactory =
                DaggerCommandProcessorFactory.create();
        CommandProcessor commandProcessor =
                commandProcessorFactory.commandProcessor();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
//            Status unused = commandProcessor.process(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

MaximumWithdrawal annotation

```
import javax.inject.Qualifier;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MaximumWithdrawal {
}
```

MinimumBalance annotation:

```
import javax.inject.Qualifier;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MinimumBalance {
}
```

Outputter Interface:

```
public interface Outputter {
    void output(String output);
}
```

SingleArgCommand:

```
import java.util.List;

abstract class SingleArgCommand implements Command {

    @Override
    public final Result handleInput(List<String> input) {
        return input.size() == 1 ? handleArg(input.get(0)) : Result.invalid();
    }

    /** Handles the single argument to the command. */
    protected abstract Result handleArg(String arg);
}
```

SystemOutModule:

```
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module
abstract public class SystemOutModule {
    @Provides
    static Outputter textOutputter() {
        return System.out::println;
    }
}
```

UserCommandsModule:

````
import dagger.Binds;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.multibindings.IntoMap;
import dagger.multibindings.StringKey;```

@Module
abstract class UserCommandsModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @StringKey("deposit")
    abstract Command depositCommand(DepositCommand command);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @StringKey("withdraw")
    abstract Command withdrawCommand(WithdrawCommand command);
}
````

UsercommandRouter:

```
import dagger.BindsInstance;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Subcomponent;
import main.Database.*;


@Subcomponent(modules = { AmountsModule.class,UserCommandsModule.class})
interface UserCommandsRouter {
    CommandRouter router();

    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory {
        UserCommandsRouter create(@BindsInstance Account account);
    }

    @Module(subcomponents = UserCommandsRouter.class)
    interface InstallationModule {}
}
```

usename Annotation:

```
import javax.inject.Qualifier;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Qualifier
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Username {
}
```

withdrawCommand Class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import main.Database.*;

public class WithdrawCommand extends BigDecimalCommand
{
    private final Account account;
    private final Outputter outputter;
    private BigDecimal minimumBalance;
    private BigDecimal maximumWithdrawal;
    @Inject
    WithdrawCommand(Outputter outputter,
                   Account account,
                    @MinimumBalance BigDecimal minimumBalance,
                    @MaximumWithdrawal BigDecimal maximumWithdrawal) {
        super(outputter);
        this.account = account;
        this.outputter = outputter;
        this.maximumWithdrawal = maximumWithdrawal;
        this.minimumBalance = minimumBalance;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        if (amount.compareTo(maximumWithdrawal) > 0) {
            outputter.output("Maximum withdrawal is violated");
            return;
        }
        BigDecimal newBalance = account.balance().subtract(amount);
        if (newBalance.compareTo(minimumBalance) < 0) {
           outputter.output("Minimum Balance is violated by user.!!");
        } else {
            account.withdraw(amount);
            outputter.output("your new balance is: " + account.balance());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `DepositCommand` class needs an `Account` as part of its parameters.
At the moment you are not telling Dagger how to provide this instance of `Account`.

Comment: it did not worked. I did what you said, but createing a module with provide function did not solved the problem. although, Dagger torurial did not provided such fuctions in their documentations.

Answer (score 0):

`UserCommandsModule` is added to the module list in the `@Subcomponent` annotated `UserCommandsRouter`. In `UserCommandsRouter`, the `Factory` subinterface has `UserCommandsRouter create(@BindsInstance account)` method defined.
Now, this `account` is accessible to every `@Binds` method, `@Provides` method and `@Inject` constructor in this subcomponent.

Inside `LoginCommand`, in the method `handleArg()`, `userCommandsRouterFactory.create()` is called with `Account` parameter.
Since, `DepositCommand` and `WithdrawCommand` are bound in `UserCommandsModule`, they get injected with the same `Account` passed in `LoginCommand` in their constructors.

Here, `Account` is valid only inside the subcomponent.
So, `UserAccountsModule` should be removed from the module list of `CommandProcessorFactory` as there is no `Account` instance it has access to, which it can  inject into `DepositCommand` and `WithdrawCommand`.

This is mentioned in the tutorial:

> The @Subcomponent annotation defines what modules Dagger should know
> about when creating instances for this subcomponent only. Just like
> @Component, it can take a list of modules: *we’ve moved the
> UserCommandsModule that declares our DepositCommand here.*

Ref: [Dagger Tutorial 10 - Only allow depositing after logging in](https://dagger.dev/tutorial/10-deposit-after-login)

So, removing `UserCommandsModule.class` from `CommandProcessorFactory` module list should fix the problem.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    LoginCommandModule.class,
    HelloWorldModule.class,
    SystemOutModule.class,

    <Remove>UserCommandsModule.class,</Remove>

    UserCommandsRouter.InstallationModule.class,
    AmountsModule.class  
})

public interface CommandProcessorFactory {
    CommandProcessor commandProcessor();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot dear kalyan. your help worked and problem now is solved. best wishes.